# In Python 3.x, how to read any number then return half of the number?

Tags: python-3.x, input

I want to ask the user to enter a number which can be float, integer and complex number, but Python 3 considers it as string if I use the input function. If I don't know what type of number the user will enter, how do I calculate the half of the input number?

Comment: Strings can be converted into floats and integers using `float()` and `int()`, respectively, but complex numbers are a more difficult problem. For starters you must state the format that your complex numbers will be in, i.e. `3+4i`

Comment: @Primusa I was told that complex number is written as $a+bj$, where $a,b \in \mathbb R$, in Python 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely interpret strings as though they were Python literals:

```
from ast import literal_eval

print(type(literal_eval("1")))  # <class 'int'>
print(type(literal_eval("1.0")))  # <class 'float'>
print(type(literal_eval("1+1j")))  # <class 'complex'>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would parse it as complex, then only print out the real part if the imaginary part is zero:

```
try:
    num = complex(input('Enter something: '))
except ValueError:
    print('Invalid input')

if num.imag:
   print(num / 2)
else:
   print(num.real / 2)
```

Another option is a nested `try`-`except`:

```
num = input('Enter something: ')

try:
    print(int(num) / 2)
except ValueError:
    try:
        print(float(num) / 2)
    except ValueError:
        try:
            print(complex(num) / 2)
        except ValueError:
            print('Invalid input')
```

Comment: Is there a float or int representation that complex won't parse?

Comment: @MadPhysicist That's why I put `complex` on the chain. It will only parse it as complex if it's not an `int` or `float`.

Comment: What I'm saying is you can just parse as complex and avoid all the nested blocks completely.

Comment: @MadPhysicist The only reason is that if you type in a normal int, say `5`, it will show `2.5+0j` instead of `2.5`.

Comment: Looks like you've successfully handled that. +1